# Create a combobox with a php associative array and insert a value into the db

Tags: php

```
<?
include_once("common_func.php");
$dataArr=array();
$dataArr["1"] = "one";
$dataArr["2"] = "two";
$dataArr["3"] = "three";

function createCombobox2($getArr,$boxName){
        $dump2 = "";
            $dump2 = "<select sTime = \"" . $boxName . "\">";
            foreach($getArr as $comKey=>$comVal){
                $dump2 .="<option value=\"" . $comKey . "\">" . $comVal . "</option>";
            }
        $dump2 .= "</select>";
        return $dump2;
    }


switch($mode){
   case "add":
        break;
             }
 ?>

 <div style="border:3 solid gray;padding:20px">
    <form action="action.php?mode=<?=$mode?>" method="post">
        <table align = "center" border="1" width="60%">

  <?  if($mode=="add") { ?>

            <tr>
            <th>접수분야</th><input name = "sField" value="<?=$noField?>" > </td>// error is here(I don't know how to define this place.) 
            </tr>
  <?  } else {  ?>
    //Skip the unnecessary part
  <?  } ?>
```

I would like to put the value of combobox in db. All other values have been inserted in db, but no progress has been made because the values in the combo box have not been inserted. If my question is wrong, I want feedback.

common_func.php

```
  function excuteQuery($mode,$fieldArr,$tableName,$whereStr,$connName){

    switch($mode){
        case "add": //Insert data
            $tmpLeft=""; $tmpRight="";
            foreach($fieldArr as $keyName => $dataVal){ 
                if(strlen($dataVal)>0){  
                    $tmpLeft  .= $keyName . ","; $tmpRight .= "\"$dataVal\",";
                }
            }
            $strSql="INSERT INTO $tableName (" .substr($tmpLeft,0,-1) . ") VALUES(" . substr($tmpRight,0,-1) . ")";
            break;
```

Comment: I am unable to even understand this code.

Comment: I recognized that the question was wrong and corrected it

Comment: There is no code given to insert anything to the database. Additionally, what do you mean by "we couldn't put in the combobox"?

Comment: I corrected the question again. I'm sorry there were so many errors in my question.

Comment: You could try to give the combobox a name. Change `$dump2 = "<select sTime = \"" . $boxName . "\">";` to `$dump2 = "<select name="combobox" sTime = \"" . $boxName . "\">";` now you can use `$_POST['combobox']` to insert the value in the database